# Add users from custom membershipprovider without enabling FBA

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication, web-application-zones

I have a Web application with 2 zones.

- Default: used by users on the inside using AD.
- Extranet: used by external users using a custom membership provider

What I want is for the users in the Default zone to be able to add users from the custom membership provider to SP groups. I can do this by enabling FBA on the Default zone. But I don't want the login page where the users in the Default-zone have to choose between Windows-authentication and Forms-authentication.

Is it possible to add forms users without enabling FBA in that zone?
Or do I have to make a custom loginpage to automatically choose windows-authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to add forms users if you created a third zone with both authentication methods, but I haven't tried it myself.

Your suggestion of making a custom login page might also work.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your answer.
I went with the "Custom Login Page" solution and that worked for me.